# Java Generics: Incompatible types when using an iterator

Tags: java, generics, types, iterator

I'm writing a test class for my generic MinPriorityQueue implementation.

I tried to iterate through the queue in two ways (i.e. Option 1 and 2). Option 1 works. Option 2 throws an error.

**Option 1**:

```
Iterator<Integer> it = q.iterator();
while(it.hasNext())
      System.out.print(it.next() + " ");
```

**Option 2**:

```
for(Integer i : q)
      System.out.print(i + " ");
```

**Question:** Why does Option 2 give me the following error (and how can I fix it)?

*main.java:17: error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Integer
    for(Integer i : q)*

[Screenshot of class main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNQ2f.png)

[Screenshot of class MinPriorityQueue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbq1n.png)

[Screenshot of abstract class PriorityQueue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FD8VO.png)

**Edit 1:** Added Screenshots of classes

Comment: What is the type of q?

Comment: Please add your class implementation... Otherwise it will be difficult to help you.

Comment: You should post your code as text, not as a screenshot. Also, you should show the implementation of  `MinPriorityQueue`. My guess is that `q.iterator` returns a raw `Iterator`.

Comment: MinPriorityQueue<Integer>

Comment: Note that you can [edit] your question.

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings and fix each "raw type" warning. That should help.

Comment: Please post your code as ***text***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `MinPriorityQueue` has a raw superclass:

```
... extends PriorityQueue
```

As such, methods inherited from that class (such as `iterator()`) will also be raw.

Make the superclass non-raw:

```
... extends PriorityQueue<E>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well most probably your `MinPriorityQueue` implementation does not implement the `Iterable<?>` interface, only in this case you can use it in loops as you try to do in option 2.

Comment: It should because it inherits from class PriorityQueue.
I tried your proposal anyways but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Notice that you need to inherit the typed PriorityQueue like this: MinPriorityQueue<T> extends PriorityQueue<T>. The last <T> is important.